# MSSQL 2012 Incorrect syntax near '>'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting this error

> Incorrect syntax near '>'

I'm comparing 2 integer and even when I use the simplest form, I still get the error message

```
select 1 >= 0
```

or

```
select cast(1 as int) >=  cast(0 as int)
```

Is there a configuration that I need to set to be able to use greater or equal to ?

Comment: Please check about `CASE WHEN` and `WHERE` syntax

Comment: What do you expect this to return? SQL Server doesn't have a boolean type (though `BIT` is usually co-opted as that)

Comment: I'm expecting a bit of 1 or 0, but seems like I won't be getting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT IIF(1 >= 0, 'YES', 'NO') -- 2012+

SELECT CASE WHEN 1 >= 0 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END

IF 1 >= 0
    SELECT 'YES'
ELSE
    SELECT 'NO'
```

Comment: I did find this 'workaround' but I'm trying not to use IIF, and why does it work in IIF and not in code, it still return a boolean for the IIF to evaluate.

Comment: You cannot select a comparison. You can only select a value of some kind. A result to a calculation, a column, an expression, but not a comparison. Though, in many coding languages, you would see that as a value of TRUE or FALSE, this is not the case in SQL. You have to evaluate the comparison yourself and then select the value. Which is why Devart's methods work.

Comment: That would explain why it works in a where clause , but if it can't be selected i will use IIF